# Click events for multiple pages

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, visual-studio-2017

How do I assign click events to buttons in an app with multiple pages?

I can do it fine with a single page app, as follows:

```
namespace Welf
{
    [Activity(Label = "Welf", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

            // Assign click event to direct to next page (page1)
            Button cmdFirst = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.cmdFirst);
            cmdFirst.Click += delegate
            {
                SetContentView(Resource.Layout.page1);
            };
        }
    }
}
```

But at what point to I assign click events for buttons on other pages?

If I do the following it doesn't work, I'm guessing because the pages aren't instantiated yet so FindByView returns a null:

```
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

            // Assign click event to direct to next page (page1)
            Button cmdFirst = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.cmdFirst);
            cmdFirst.Click += delegate
            {
                SetContentView(Resource.Layout.page1);
            };

            // This assignment doesn't work
            Button cmdSecond = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.cmdSecond);
            cmdSecond.Click += delegate
            {
                SetContentView(Resource.Layout.page3);
            }
        }
    }
```

...and the following does work, but then I get into trouble with repeat visits to the same page because I'm adding the event a second time:

```
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

            // Assign click event to direct to next page (page1)
            Button cmdFirst = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.cmdFirst);
            cmdFirst.Click += delegate
            {
                SetContentView(Resource.Layout.page1);

                // This click works the first time only, for obvious reasons
                Button cmdSecond = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.cmdSecond);
                cmdSecond.Click += delegate
                {
                    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.page3);
                }
            };
        }
    }
```

So how should I do it?

Comment: Typically one Activity is assigned/associated to one layout... either use multiple activities or use Fragments. https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/hello,android_multiscreen/

Comment: Yeah I had a look at that, but it seems incomplete unless I got it wrong. E.g. it says "In the MainActivity class, add the following code to register the Translation History button (place this line after the translationHistory declaration)" but followed the tutorial and I have no such declaration. I would really appreciate an example.

Comment: Download one of the linked project samples associated to those guides.

Comment: Actually I can't see how that example helps as there are no buttons to assign events to on the second page anyway. I guess I'll keep looking unless someone provides an answer...

Comment: Hang on a sec (sorry new to this) - an activity is the class associated with a layout, right? So MainActivity would be for the Main layout, etc. That means the startup code for layout Page1 should be in Page1Activity...

Comment: The names do not matter but yes, one Activity for one layout

Comment: So, where in the Activity should I code the events? `OnCreate` only seems to work for the default layout.

Comment: Don't worry - I think I'm just going to define the click events in the XAML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only call SetContentView() once in any activity. What you need to do here is make a new activity. 
1: Right click on your project and click new item. 
2: Create a new activity and a new Android layout. 
3: Then in your new Activity.cs call SetContentView for your new layout you just created. 
4: Then use this code to call your new activity: `Intent intent = new Intent(this,typeof(mynewactivityname));
StartActivity(intent);`